# How do I access NFC capabilities using Flutter or React Native?

Tags: react-native, nfc, flutter, mobile-application

I'm trying to decide which language to learn so I can program an mobile app that revolves around NFC and your location. I heard Flutter and Reactive Native are two relatively new languages that allows you to write code for both iOS and Android and there's courses for them on Udemy. However when I Google searched "NFC Flutter" there wasn't any relevant articles on how to incorporate NFC. Is it worth learning either of the two languages or should I write my app separately in Swift and Java?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either React Native or Flutter and still have NFC capabilities.

- For **Flutter** there is [this plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_nfc_reader) you could try (haven't tested it myself)
- For **React Native** you could use [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-nfc-manager) which is tested and works great

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing this answer there is no full solution for NFC in flutter.

That said, you can implement NFC functionality using [PlatformChannels](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/). Or, better, encapsulate in in a [plugin](https://flutter.io/developing-packages/#plugin).

That way, you can write a code for your app in dart for both platforms, but NFC functionality will call Native Swift or Java code to handle platform specifics.

[Here is one plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/nfc) that is still Work in progress, that does the exact same thing for Android only. You could, for example, fork the plugin and add iOS code and there you would have full solution.